# Override "X-Robots-Tag: noindex" in Tumblr

Tags: javascript, http-headers, seo, tumblr, x-robots-tag

Tumblr automatically inserts a "X-Robots-Tag: noindex" line in the HTTP header for all tagged pages; e.g. "blog.tumblr.com/tagged/tag". Is there a way to override this? Or is there a way to modify the header in any way using scripts or any other tool?

Comment: Afaik, no. The header will be included server side, which we have no control over.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess even if the header is modified by javascript after the page loads, it would be too late as the googlebot will have already followed the directive in the header, correct? If so, I guess there is nothing that can be done about this?

Comment: I believe you are correct. The headers will already be set / read.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to override this?

As mentioned by [mikedidthis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312574/mikedidthis) in the comments, ***NO***. The header will be included server side

*PS: adding an answer so this question doesn't appear as missing an answer.*